# How to not replace the word that has already been replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
<script>
    function TransposeDown() {
        $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/C/g, 'B'));
        $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/B/g, 'Bb'));
    }
</script>

<button onclick="TransposeDown();">Transpose Down</button>
<span class="hcrd">C</span>
<span class="hcrd">B</span>
<span class="hcrd">C</span>
```

The problem is that once the `button` is clicked, the text inside all the `<span>` tags change to "Bb". But what I want is the first and the last `span`'s text to change to "B" and the second one's text to change to "Bb" only.

How do I do this? Is there any way to do this in such a way that the function is done only once? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well the simplest answer would be to just swap your two lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are obviously trying to transpose musical chords, I'd go for a solution using `data-original` to store the original note, and keep track of how many times the user has transposed the notes. This way you can easily reset the whole thing.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjolie/b5ghxLoL/1/

*Update: Out of the box, this doesn't work with any 6th, 7th, maj, min etc, but this can also be stored as a data attribute, and be appended to the output.*

```js
var notes = ["A", "Bb", "B", "C", "Db", "D", "Eb", "E", "F", "Gb", "G", "Ab"];

var transposed = 0;

function transpose() {
  var chords = document.querySelectorAll('.hcrd');
  var chord = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < chords.length; i++) {
    chord = chords[i].dataset['original'];
    chords[i].innerHTML = getNewChord(chord);
  }
}

function getNewChord(chord) {
  var origIndex = notes.indexOf(chord);
  if (origIndex === -1) {
    // Invalid chord
    return chord;
  }
  if (origIndex + transposed < 0) {
    return notes[notes.length + transposed + origIndex];
  }
  return notes[origIndex + transposed];
}

function transposeDown() {
  transposed -= 1;

  if(transposed === -12){
 transposed = 0;
  }
  transpose();
}

function reset() {
  transposed = 0;
  transpose();
}

document.querySelector('#transposedown').addEventListener('click', transposeDown, false);
document.querySelector('#reset').addEventListener('click', reset, false)
```

```html
<span class="hcrd" data-original="C">C</span>
<span class="hcrd" data-original="B">B</span>
<span class="hcrd" data-original="C">C</span>
<span class="hcrd" data-original="G">G</span>
<span class="hcrd" data-original="E">E</span>

<button id="transposedown">Transpose down</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: It will be nice to put your code in a snippet in here. It will still be working and users will be able to see it here.

Comment: @xpy Bear with me, I'm new here :)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. But the problem here is that I have already created a whole website using the mentioned structure, but have not added the data-original="" tag to any of the chords.
Is there any way to do this code without the data-original="" tag?

Comment: Injecting `data-original` with javascript on page load isn't hard, but it gets complicated when you have other chords than the basic ones. You need logic to transpose e.g. Cmaj7 or Am anyway, and keeping track of this in a way computers can easily understand is recommended. So my two cents is that taking the time to reformat the markup is a good investment. Example to get you going: `<span data-original="C" data-suffix="maj7">Cmaj7</span>`

Comment: @Chordzone.org Putting your values in `data-attributes` is the best thing to do.

Comment: Ok. I'll reformat the code to include the 'data-attributes'. But can you please help me out with retaining the 'data-suffix'? When I ran the code, the suffix disappeared. And what change do I have to make to create a 'TransposeUp()' function?

Comment: The code snippets here are a pain to update, but check out the new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjolie/b5ghxLoL/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can either invert, which works in simple instances, or you can do it like this, which works even in complex instances:

```
var string = "A B C D";

string = string.replace(/(C)|(B)/g,function(str,p1,p2) {
    if(p1) return 'B';
    if(p2) return 'Bb';
});
```

So in your case, it would be:

```
 $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/(C)|(B)/g,function(str,p1,p2) {
    if(p1) return 'B';
    if(p2) return 'Bb';
 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply invert your two methods, starting with the B replacement then with the C one:

```
function TransposeDown() {
    $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/B/g, 'Bb'));
    $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/C/g, 'B'));
}
```

You could also transpose to a special pattern (for example prefixing all transpositions by a special tag) then make sure to exclude this tag from the regexes. Finally, remove the special pattern from the whole document. This would take longer, but would allow you to not take order into account

Answer (score 1):

As a more general solution, you could consider writing a regex that matches both and using a function to determine the replacement.  This would work for arbitrary search/replace as it does it all in one pass.

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/(B|C)/g, function(match) {
  switch (match) {
    case 'B':
      return 'Bb';
    case 'C':
      return 'B';
  }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change them in sequence by selecting them all with a common selector, then skip the change if the element has changed.

```js
var rules = [{
      regEx: /^C$/g,
      str: 'B'
    }, {
      regEx: /^B$/g,
      str: 'Bb'
    }];

function TransposeDown() {
  $(".hcrd").each(function(index, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    var prevVal = $(el).html();
    var newVal = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
      newVal = $el.html().replace(rules[i].regEx, rules[i].str);
      if (newVal != prevVal) {
        $el.html(newVal);
        break;
      }
    }

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="TransposeDown();">Transpose Down</button>
<span class="hcrd">C</span>
<span class="hcrd">B</span>
<span class="hcrd">C</span>
```

Comment: This worked great the first time. But when I press it the second time, it does not work out well.

In this case, the "C"s changed to "Bb" and the "B" changed to "Bb".
One the second click, I wanted the "B" to change to "Bb" only, but the "Bb" changes to "Bbb" as well.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

as @dannyjolie explained, I am trying to transpose musical chords.

Comment: I changed the regEx so I suppose it should work the way you do but I believe @dannyjolie answer is the most efficient and straightforward yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently..

```
<script>
function TransposeDown(){
     $("#C").html(text.replace("C", "B"));
     $("#B").html(text.replace("B", "Bb"));
}
</script>

<button onclick="TransposeDown();">Transpose Down</button>
<span class="hcrd" id="C">C</span>
<span class="hcrd" id="B">B</span>
<span class="hcrd" id="C">C</span>
```